# Zeros of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, roots

Let $f(x) = \int_0^\infty g(x,t)dt$, then how can we find the number of zeros (or an upper bound for the number of zeros) of f(x)? 
  For example,

What about $f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x}\sum_1^n c_{i}t^{\mu_{i}} dt$?,
 where $c_{i}$ are non zero real numbers and $0< \mu_{1}<\ldots<\mu_{n}$ are positive real numbers.

Comment: The first $f$ is not defined, since $ \int_0^\infty t^{\mu_{i}}dt=+\infty$. The second one is constant.

Comment: Your expression is a linear combination of Gamma values. But where is $x$ ?

Comment: Sorry. I edit it